# rendering trim function within ternary operator

Tags: php, syntax, ternary-operator

I want to use the **trim()** function within a **Ternary operation** but it does not work. below is my code:

```
$mainJob = ($user->getMainJob() != null) ? "-a-{trim($user->getMainJob())}" : null;
```

i also tried this:

```
$mainJob = ($user->getMainJob() != null) ? "-a-'.trim({$user->getMainJob()}).'" : null;
```

would appreciate any advice on how to render it within the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string concatentation is the issue, not the usage of trim within a ternary.

```
$mainJob = ($user->getMainJob() != null) ? "-a-".trim($user->getMainJob()) : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do proper quoting and concatenating strings with var Try

```
$mainJob = ($user->getMainJob() != null) ? "-a-".trim($user->getMainJob()) : null;
```